# dnsmasq doesn't resolve internal IP address

Tags: dns, openwrt, dnsmasq

I have a openwrt router, and a client linux connected to it. I config the dnsmasq with

```
resolv-file=/tmp/resolv.conf.auto
```

For example, when I use nslookup on the client, `nslookup google.com` is OK, but `nslookup bd.ysmood.org` says `No answer`.

How to make the router work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, since the bd.ysmood.org is an internal IP address. The dnsmasq's `rebind_protection` will make the lookup fail.

Edit the `/etc/config/dhcp`, find the line:

```
option rebind_protection 1
```

Change the `1` to `0` will do it.